# Transparent the background of the text

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm almost done, but my problem is the background of the text , I even try the opacity but the underline of the box appear.

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  }
.paddingbox{
  padding: 60px;}
.boxed {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-top: -2em;
 }
```

```html
<div class="paddingbox"><center> 
<div class="block">
<span class="boxed">
 <h1 style="color:white;"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1></span>
  </div></center></div>
```

With backgroun color
[image: with box color]

without background color

[image: without background color]

I'm trying to achive is like this, but it have a back ground like in the picture above

[image]

I tried fieldset and this happen

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: okay w8 i will update my question

Comment: okay i already put the one i want to achive

Answer (score 1):

The behavior can be achieved with a [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) tag.

```css
.block{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.title{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

body{
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="block">
  <legend class="title">
    Services
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I already  do  the fieldset, but what I got is only underline in the bottom

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: can you make a screenshot of my example ? i think this should work in all browsers

Comment: @Woshooo `fieldset` is [compatible with all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: w8 i will screeshot it

Comment: click on a the "Run code snippet" in my post and make a screenshot of it (if it doesnt work), if you cant implement my solution you can create a new questions, on why the fieldset does not show the wantet behaviour

Comment: also I'm using it in wordpress any issues there? okay thanks :)

Comment: no this is basic html/css and works with every content management system which can include html/css.

Answer (score 0):

*I get help of `position`s for solve this question!*

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span>About Us</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you would still have a solid background-color, that overlays the background-image

Comment: @fehrlich,  yes,this is for one time!

Comment: it still overlays the background image